# Filebeat - NGINX: Add logfile name as field

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am currently setting up an ELK stack. I am struggling with the configuration that the NGINX Filebeat module does not send the full file name of the logfile.

In Kibana I see the following document properties of an entry:

```
[...]
event.dataset: nginx.access
event.module: nginx
agent.type: filebeat
agent.version: 8.7.1
ecs.version: 1.12.0
[...]
```

Since there are several access log files reported by Logstash NGINX, it is not possible to differentiate.

Is there a possibility to also transmit the file name?

Alternatively, it would probably be possible to configure multiple NGINX inputs. Are there any other possible solutions?

Thanks a lot!